# Flex tab navigator: initialize hidden tabs

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tabs

My problem: I have a tab navigator, with many forms in each tab. But I have a single global save button. Problem is, if I don't open a Tab, it doesn't get initialized and therefore the forms it contains do not exist..

How Can I make it as if the user had clicked on every tab?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

set its `creationPolicy` to `"all"`

```
<mx:TabNavigator creationPolicy="all">
    <!--Children-->
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using [SuperTabNavigator](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/containers/SuperTabNavigator.html) which  is an extension of the TabNavigator navigation container

I used the below script to initialize all tabs

```
private function initMainTab():void 
    { 
        for (var i:int = 0; i < superTabNav.getChildren().length ; i++)  
        { 
            superTabNav.selectedIndex = i; 
            superTabNav.validateNow();      
        } 
        superTabNav.selectedIndex = 0; 
    }
```